# How to write if an account name already exists, use an account name appended with an integer to distinguish different account names

Tags: python

I have already made a list of names. Here's are the question, For the account name above, if an account name already exists, use an account name appended with an integer to distinguish different account names. For example, if there are three patients with the same account name `"abranch"`, the second one should be named as `"abranch1"` and the third one should be named as `"abranch2"`. Much appreciate if you can help!

Here's are my template of the name list：

```
patient_name = []

with open('all_patients.txt', 'r') as fh:

    for line in fh:

        splited_list = line.split()
        surname = splited_list[1]
        given_name = splited_list[0][0]
        patient_name_u = given_name + surname
        patient_name.append(patient_name_u.lower())
```

Comment: You must have a lookup table, you don't want to handle edge cases where the user makes an account named "abranch9999" and the algorithm decided that the next account should be named "abranch10000". I suggest making a dictionary where each username is linked with the amount of their duplication, e.g {"abranch": 2, "joe": 3} for 2 "abranch" and 3 "joe" existed in the database

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# simple test
patient_names = ['john','john','andy']
# count the names in the list
patient_names_count = defaultdict(int)
# new names
new_patient_names = []
# iterate the names
for name in patient_names:
    # first one, no need to change
    if name not in patient_names_count:
        patient_names_count[name]+=1
        new_patient_names.append(name)
    # append with an integer
    else:
        new_name = name+str(patient_names_count[name])
        patient_names_count[name]+=1
        new_patient_names.append(new_name)
print(new_patient_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import Dict

# contains usernames and number of duplicates
user_names: Dict[str, int] = {"username": 0}


def choose_username(a_name: str):
    if a_name not in user_names:
        return a_name
    else:
        name_suffix = user_names[a_name] + 1
        user_names[a_name] = name_suffix
        return f"{a_name}{name_suffix}"
```